# How can I convert the Python list into Python Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to convert the list values into the Python Dataframe but my header values are inside the list.

the values which are inside the list are like this:

```
cols_head=['BATSMEN', '', 'R', 'B', '4s', '6s', 'SR', '', 'C Hemraj', 'c Mohammad Mithun b Mehidy Hasan Miraz', '9', '17', '2', '0', '52.94', '']
```

I have scraped the values from the espn website and it is score card now when the values are inside the list i want to convert them into the pandas dataframe. When I have convert the list into the dataframe I am getting the like this:

```
              0
    0   BATSMEN
    1   Out
    2   R
    3   B
    4   4s
    5   6s
    6   SR
    7   
    8   C Hemraj
    9   c Mohammad Mithun b Mehidy Hasan Miraz
    10  9
    11  17
    12  2
    13  0
    14  52.94
```

from serial 0 to 7 these are columns of the dataframe

This is the code which I have tried to convert the values:

```
    cols_head=[x.text.strip() for x in cell]
    #print(cols_head)    
     List_values=cols_head[:-13]
    df=pd.DataFrame(List_values)
```

**I want to the output of the dataframe like this**:

```
         BATSMEN      Out               R    B    4s   6s    SR
  1    C Hemraj  C Mohammad Mithun      9    17   2     0    52.94
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension. This extends under the assumption your list contains an arbitrary number of rows in the same format. Notice you actually have 8 columns. The last is just labeled with an empty string.

```
data = ['BATSMEN', '', 'R', 'B', '4s', '6s', 'SR', '', 'C Hemraj', 'c Mohammad Mithun b Mehidy Hasan Miraz', '9', '17', '2', '0', '52.94', '']

n = 8
df = pd.DataFrame([data[n*i:n*(i+1)] for i in range(1, len(data) // n)],
                  columns=data[:n])

print(df)

#     BATSMEN                                          R   B 4s 6s     SR  
# 0  C Hemraj  c Mohammad Mithun b Mehidy Hasan Miraz  9  17  2  0  52.94  

print(df.columns)

# Index(['BATSMEN', '', 'R', 'B', '4s', '6s', 'SR', ''], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for the data you have posted. It will need to be tweaked slightly if your list actually contains multiple rows of data.

```
import pandas as pd

cols_head=['BATSMEN', '', 'R', 'B', '4s', '6s', 'SR', '', 'C Hemraj', 'c Mohammad Mithun b Mehidy Hasan Miraz', '9', '17', '2', '0', '52.94', '']
headers = cols_head[:7]
data = cols_head[8:-1]  # Ignores the two blanks at index 7 and 15
df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=headers)
```

Output:

```
    BATSMEN                                          R   B 4s 6s     SR
0  C Hemraj  c Mohammad Mithun b Mehidy Hasan Miraz  9  17  2  0  52.94
```